# Laplace transform of translated convolution

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I need to calculate the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L_t}$ of the function

$$ h(t)=\int_0^{\tau-t}f(\tau-t-u)g(u)du, $$

in terms of $\mathcal{L_t}[(f\ast g)(t)]$. Here, I do not know $g$ and $\tau>t>0$. I am trying to use the property

$$\mathcal{L_t}[(f\ast g)(\tau-t)] = \mathcal{L_t}[f(\tau-t)]\mathcal{L_t}[g(\tau-t)],$$

but doing an example it seems to not be correct. I am also using the properties of Laplace transform of translation and multiplication of sign, but without success. Does someone know an interesting property for this case?

Comment: Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems ? Specfically the rules for "Time shifting", "Time scaling" and convolution.

Comment: @StiftungWarentest Applying those rules, the result is $\mathcal{L_t}[h(t)]=\mathcal{L_t}[f(t),-s]\mathcal{L_t}[g(\tau-t),s]$. But evaluating a simple example, it does not work.

Comment: I think it should be $\mathcal{L}_t[h(t)] = -e^{\tau s}\mathcal{L}_t[f](-s)\cdot \mathcal{L}_t[g](-s)$, try that

Comment: @StiftungWarentest It doesn't work either. I think the hypotheses behind those properties do not allow us to use them in this particular case.